# Differences in antonyms of "balance" with negative prefixes

Tags: grammaticality, synonyms, word-usage, antonyms, negative-prefixes

Most words only have one correct negative prefix out of "in-", "im-", and "un-". Why are both "imbalance" and "unbalance" both grammatically correct (but "inbalance" is not")? What are differences in meaning and usage of these two opposites of "balance"? Can they be regarded as synonyms of each other? Are there any other examples of such co-existing variants with different uses?

Comment: Have you looked these words up in (say) the Oxford Dictionaries online?  If you did, you will have noticed one important grammatical difference.  As you know, ELU asks for questioners to indicate their conclusions from their own research and set out their question in the light of that.  Of course, sometimes ‘the exception proves the rule’!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About ***im-***, [etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/im-) explains:

> variant of *in-* ***before -b-, -m-, -p-*** in the sense of "*not, opposite of*"

Bear in mind that ***[in-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/in-?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_6285)*** comes from Latin, and so it will follow Latin phonetic assimilation:

> *In-* is a word-forming element meaning "not, opposite of, without" (also *im-,* il-, ir- ***by assimilation of -n- with following consonant, a tendency which began in later Latin***).

Therefore, before ***b, m or p*** the prefix ***in-*** will always become ***im-***. <sup>1</sup>

As for ***[un-](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=un-)***, the same Etymoline says it is a:

> prefix of negation, ***Old English un-***, from Proto-Germanic *un-.

***Un-*** never becomes *um-, because it is not a Latin prefix.

Etymoline goes on to explain the difference in use of *un-* and *in-* (and its variants):

***Un- is the most prolific of English prefixes***, freely and widely used in Old English, where it forms more than 1,000 compounds. It underwent a mass extinction in early Middle English, but emerged with renewed vigor 16c. *to form compounds with native and imported words*. ***It disputes with Latin-derived cognate in- the right to form the negation of certain words*** (indigestable/undigestable, etc.), ***and though both might be deployed in cooperation to indicate shades of meaning*** (unfamous/infamous), ***typically they are not***.

<sup><sup>1</sup> I underline that when it is a **prefix**, it changes into *-im*. You do find such occurrences as ***input*** (where ***in*** comes from an adverb). So do not confuse *inpatient* (a patient who lives in hospital while under treatment.) with *impatient* (not patient)!</sup>

---

As for the difference in meaning between *imbalance* and *unbalance*, ***imbalance*** seems to refer more to a lack of balance in quantity or quality among the components of a whole, whereas ***unbalance*** can refer to the lack of (physical or mental) equilibrium.

About ***imbalance***,[Vocabulary.com](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disbalance_NOUN%2C%20unbalance_NOUN%2C%20imbalance_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisbalance_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunbalance_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimbalance_NOUN%3B%2Cc0) says:

> An imbalance occurs when you have too much of some things and too
> little of others. If you put so much pepper in your soup that you
> can't taste the other spices, then you caused an imbalance in your
> flavoring.

About ***unbalance***, [the same dictionary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/unbalance) gives two first definitions to it ***as a verb***, but it does also record its use as a noun:

> ***To unbalance*** is to make unsteady or uneven. A sudden gust of wind
> might unbalance you when you're on a sailboat — don't forget to wear a
> life jacket!
>
> Throw something off balance, and you unbalance it. Tickling someone
> who's in a one-legged yoga stance will unbalance them, and leaning too
> far to one side will unbalance a new bike rider. You can also call
> this state of being out of kilter or wobbly unbalance: "The unbalance
> of the tightrope walker made me glad there was a net underneath him!"
> And figuratively, unbalance can also mean "disturb or upset."

Now I might "alarm" you even more, if I tell you that there is a third antonym of balance: ***[disbalance](https://www.wordsense.eu/disbalance/)***, but you can be at peace, it is rarely used (with a particular connotation of *disturbed/upset* balance).

Concluding, I will just add this [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disbalance_NOUN%2C%20unbalance_NOUN%2C%20imbalance_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisbalance_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunbalance_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimbalance_NOUN%3B%2Cc0) that shows how the three terms are compared in use: ***imbalance*** is the most common.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive and thoroughly researched answer. It is very thought provoking. I wonder if the prefixes a- or anti- (presumably originating in Greek) are also competing with the Latin and Proto-Germanic prefixes.

Comment: Yes, it would be interesting to find out. You can ask a different question.